# Not quoting a scalar starting with the "%" indicator character is deprecated since Symfony 3.1

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, deprecated, symfony-plugins

All my services and parameters from **services.yml** are striked and I get the message **"Not quoting a scalar starting with the "%" indicator character is deprecated since Symfony 3.1"**.
But I am using **Symfony 2.6** and I don't want to put the values in quotes since it is not needed for this version. This happened only after I updated my Symfony Plugin for PhpStorm 2016.1

What can I do to avoid this? (using PhpStorm 10 or using an older plugin is not an option)

Answer (score 8):

What you need to do is embrace it with double quotes.

Before:

```
services:
  foo.class:
    class: Foo\Class
    arguments:
      - @some.service
      - %some.parameter%
```

After:

```
services:
  foo.class:
    class: Foo\Class
    arguments:
      - "@some.service"
      - "%some.parameter%"
```

Comment: Yes, this could solve my problem, but I already specified that I don't want this ("I don't want to put the values in quotes ").
This means that I should change my code, and I don't want to.
But thank you anyway.

Comment: I see, you have a point, I got confused that you were using sf 2.6, sorry for that! I don't think the plugin is supporting multiple versions of sf! :/

Comment: The correct way is `'@some.service'` with a single quote actually!

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo as a sf2 developer according to their documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings if you use double quote you would have to escape some of its content, actually it may not be true, i dont know if you need to do this "\@service" anyway with single quotes you dont need to backslash anything so i'd say its the correct way? double quotes should be used for text like
`arguments: ["This is a string argument \n With a breakline using \\n (this last one is escaped!"]`

Comment: From Symfony docs:
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-yaml-deprecations

" In Symfony 3.1, the usage of % at the beginning of an unquoted string
 is deprecated and it will be removed in Symfony 4.0. The solution is
 simple but a bit tiresome: wrap these strings with single or double
 quotes"

Answer (score 4):

The inspection you mention is not provided by PhpStorm 2016.1 but by the `Symfony Plugin` plugin.

As with any other inspection, it can be easily disabled if you press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd><sup>*</sup> or click on the yellow bulb that appears at the start of the offending line then select `Disable inspection` from the submenu of `Inspection 'Yaml escaped \ in quoted inspection' options`.

You can also find this inspection in the `Settings`/`Preference` window, under `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `Symfony` -> `Twig`.

---

* I am using PhpStorm on OSX and this is the key combination on the default keymap.

Comment: I don't find this a good option for me.  I'm using Symfony 2.6. Why am I receiving a message about something that is in Symfony 3.1?
That is the situation I want to avoid.

Comment: Apparently the `Symfony Plugin` plugin doesn't provide a way to specify what version of Symfony do you use and it also probably doesn't try to detect this by itself. You can try to ask this feature on the [plugin's GitHUb page](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin-doc/issues). Anyway, Symfony 2.6 is a version that passed its [maintenance period](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule) (including the *fourteen month* period for security issue fixes). You should step forward and migrate the project to a newer version.

Comment: Unfortunately migration is not an option. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: In this case, disabling this inspection (and probably a few other ones) is your only option for now. It happens to me too to not agree with some PhpStorm inspections and disable some of them when they become annoying.

Comment: Disabling this inspection also affect other parts of the code. And I don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

starting with the “%” is deprecated since the version 2.8 ;)

[New in Symfony 2.8: YAML deprecations](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-yaml-deprecations)

Comment: I know, but I am using 2.6 :)

Comment: Okey @taysia09, It is certainly of in the plugin "Symfony Plugin" :/
Good luck :)

Comment: actually scalar values '%' is deprecated since the version 3.1! @ from 2.8 :) 
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-yaml-deprecations and
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-yaml-deprecations